# css text-overflow: ellipsis does not work properly on span

Tags: html, css, sass, overflow

I have a span in a div like this:

[image]

As you can see, the text gets overflowed, but not with the three dots, as usual, when you use `text-overflow: ellipsis`.

This is my relevant html:

```
<div class="row main">
    <span class="kurzbezeichnung">
      <mat-icon svgIcon="file"></mat-icon>
      Hello! This is a longer text to see if overflow ellipsis effect will get
      applied!
    </span>

    //here is some more stuff of course, but this is the relevant code
</div>
```

This is the relevant CSS:

```
.row {
  & span {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 6px;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
}

.kurzbezeichnung {
  width: 150px;
  max-width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 18px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Why does it overflow without the three dots?

Answer (score 1):

Change the span tag to div and add a 'white-space:nowrap' to the class

HTML

```
<div class="row main">
    <div class="kurzbezeichnung">
      <mat-icon svgIcon="file"></mat-icon>
      Hello! This is a longer text to see if overflow ellipsis effect will get
      applied!
    </div>

    //here is some more stuff of course, but this is the relevant code
</div>
```

CSS

```
.row {
  & span {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 6px;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
}

.kurzbezeichnung {
  width: 150px;
  max-width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
   white-space: nowrap;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 18px;
  width: 100%;
}
```